# Block->toHtml() dosn't have template

Tags: magento-1.9, template

I have a function like that:

```
public function aAction()
{
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_options');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $block->setProduct($product);
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
```

the method `toHtml` doesn't have a template set and returns nothing.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function aAction()
{
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_options');
    //add this line.
    $block->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/options.phtml');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $block->setProduct($product);
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
```

But this might now work properly because the options block makes use of options renderes to render different types of options.

So you can try this:

```
public function aAction()
{
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $optionRenderers = array(
          'text' => array (
               'block' => ' catalog/product_view_options_type_text',
               'template' => 'catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml',
           ),
           'file' => array (
               'block' => ' catalog/product_view_options_type_file',
               'template' => 'catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml',
           ),
           'select' => array (
               'block' => ' catalog/product_view_options_type_select',
               'template' => 'catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml',
           ),
           'date' => array (
               'block' => ' catalog/product_view_options_type_date',
               'template' => 'catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml',
           ),
    )
    $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_options');
    $block->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/options.phtml');
    foreach ($optionRenderers as $type => $settings) {
        $block->addOptionRenderer($type, $settings['block'], $settings['template']);
    }
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $block->setProduct($product);
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: I've tried. But also returns empty html. I tracked the code and it seems that dosn.t make `fetchView() `function from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` correct. But i'm not sure. Any idea?

Comment: @ana.coman93 I have no idea why. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

you have not assign any template and also `toHtml()` method is not here for `setTemplate()` method.

You can try below code

```
public function aAction()
{
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_options');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $block->setProduct($product);
    $block->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/options.phtml'); //set template you can pass your own template if you have created.  
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
```